# Leaving swipe to delete button open on uitableview cell then going back causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I have swipe to delete on one of my table cells. If I swipe right on the table cell to display the delete button and pop the view by pressing the back button the app crashes with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've already singled this out as the reason it crashes. Why does this happen?

This is what it looks like when I tap back https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggn4jqr0ox0tnta/Screenshot%202014-12-04%2023.39.25.png?dl=0

Comment: Add exception breakpoint to find place where application crash which will lead you to the right direction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `UITableview` end editing to NO in `viewWillDisappear`

```
[tableview setEditing:NO];
```

Comment: Seems only to happen in Swift projects.

Answer (score 0):

Where you remove your cell from table view. You also have to delete data from you array.

Comment: I'm not even pressing delete. I'm just swiping right

Answer (score 0):

When you are swiping right, may be you are popping the controller. Because the view is disappearing, you have to write NANNAV's lines.

Answer (score 0):

This caused because delegate and datasource of the table is simple assign pointer, not weak. So after deleting view controller, containing table still can send events to the controller. To avoid this you can manually set tableview delegate and datasouce to nil in dealloc method. BTW, this happens not only with tables.